# Developing Android app on API 10 - will it still run on devices with API 7?

Tags: android, api

I am kind of new to Android world and have a simple question.

If I develop an app *using libraries on API 13 (or API10)* will this app still run on Android phones which *have only API 7* installed?

When I try to run my current app with EClipse on my Android phone with API 7 I get an error message that *my app requires at least API 10* - so I am afraid to develop on API 13.

**Should I better just stick to API 7 and not use the new features?**

Whats the best thing to do in this situation?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work if you are not using any function from API10 which is not present in the older APIs.

You can still use the new functions with reflection. 
First check if the function is available, then execute it with reflection.

Example:

```
    // try to override the transition animation
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT) {
      try {
        Method method = getClass().getMethod("overridePendingTransition",
            new Class[]{int.class, int.class});
        method.invoke(this, 0, 0);
      } catch (Throwable e) {
        // can not override transition animation, so do nothing
      }
    }
```

Also make sure you set android:minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 1):

You generally want to develop using the minimum API version possible for the features your program requires.  This will allow it to work on the most devices.

API 7 devices can run API 7 and lower.

Comment: So API 7 devices CANNOT run API 10 compiled apps?

Answer (score 1):

The message you get is just a response to what is set in the manifest file. You can change the min API version for your application:

```
<manifest android:minSdkVersion="9"> </manifest>
```

As Heuristic said, you should use the minimal API version because of compatibility reasons, but if your application uses libraries from a newer version of the one installed on the phone, the app will not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a true minimum API level you should develop for that level and with the appropriate minSDKVersion flag set so that your application won't even appear in the marketplace for devices that do not meet that standard. In general answer to your question, the minimum possible requirements will depend on what features of the API you take advantage of. If you want to provide backwards compatibility but still want to use some of the features in the newer API I think you're going to need to create two versions of your application and set the min/target/max SDK flags appropriately so customers get the version best suited to their device.

You can check out the Android API listing to see what the differences are between each level to determine if there's some functionality you'll really want to use.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html