# If I use Android 4.2.2 API 17 to develop my app it can run in oldest versions?

Tags: android

If I use Android 4.2.2 API 17 to develop my app it can run in oldest versions, like a tablet running an android 4.0 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to code backward compatible new feature in Android SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558638/how-to-code-backward-compatible-new-feature-in-android-sdk). Title is not quite the same, but content of this question is covered. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822497/developing-android-app-on-api-10-will-it-still-run-on-devices-with-api-7?rq=1 and many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be backwards compatible with older versions of Android if you include the following:

```
"In your AndroidManifest.xml file declare the following (replacing the platform versions      with whatever your app requires):

<!-- Build Target -->
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14" android:minSdkVersion="7" />"
```

See answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558638/how-to-code-backward-compatible-new-feature-in-android-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

> If I use Android 4.2.2 API 17 to develop my app it can run in oldest versions

If you specify the in `Androidmanifest.xml` min and target Sdk version then its can can be installed within that range.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```